# How do I correct redirection htacces?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this page:

[link](http://dizievents.ch)

```
pass:dizi
```

I want to create a redirect in .htacces.

This is my code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress


    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]



    </IfModule>

Redirect 301 / http://dizievents.ch/index.php/event/food-n-liquor-dizinvolta-2/
#if i put this code appears an error
```

I put an image to understand better what error I have

http://i61.tinypic.com/6tlr0o.jpg

Basically it enters infinite loop while (what I think)

What can I do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Redirect` line?